# Why does my rspec test fail?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I have problem with my "POST create" action. Test passed successfully, when attributes are valid, but when they are invalid, player is also saved. It's strange because, only :invalid_player, can be saved with invalid attributes. If I change for example, wins to -1 or "string", player with attributes :invalid_player is saved. But if I change attributes for :player, like wins = -1, validators prevent player, from being saved.

Console output with error message:

```
Failures:

  1) PlayersController user is signed in POST create with invalid attributes does not save the new player
     Failure/Error:
       expect{
         post :create, { tournament_id: @tournament, player: FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:invalid_player) }
       }.to_not change(Player, :count)

       expected #count not to have changed, but did change from 1 to 2
     # ./spec/controllers/players_controller_spec.rb:111:in `block (5 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

This is my Player model:

```
class Player < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :tournament

  validates :wins,  numericality: { only_integer: true, greater_than_or_equal_to: 0 }
  validates :loses, numericality: { only_integer: true, greater_than_or_equal_to: 0 }
  validates :draws, numericality: { only_integer: true, greater_than_or_equal_to: 0 }

end
```

Factory file for players:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :player do
    wins 0
    loses 0
    draws 0

  end

  factory :invalid_player, parent: :player do
    wins -1
    loses 0
    draws 0

  end

end
```

Spec test:

```
 context "user is signed in" do

    before do
      @tournament = create(:tournament)
      @player = create(:player)
      @user = create(:user)
      @request.env["devise.mapping"] = Devise.mappings[:user]
      sign_in(@user)
      controller.stub(:current_user).and_return(@user)
    end

    describe "GET new" do
    end

    describe "GET index" do
      it "renders the :index view" do
        get :index, tournament_id: @tournament
        expect(response).to render_template :index
      end
    end

    describe "GET show" do
      it "renders the :show view" do
        get :show, { id: @player, tournament_id: @tournament }
        expect(response).to render_template :show
      end
    end

    describe "POST create" do
      context "with valid attributes" do
        it "creates a new player" do
          expect{
            post :create, { tournament_id: @tournament, player: FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:player) }
          }.to change(Player,:count).by(1)
        end

        it "redirects to the tournament" do
          post :create, { tournament_id: @tournament, player: FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:player) }
          expect(response).to redirect_to @tournament
        end
      end

      context "with invalid attributes" do
        it "does not save the new player" do
          expect{
            post :create, { tournament_id: @tournament, player: FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:invalid_player) }
          }.to_not change(Player, :count)
        end

        it 're-renders the new method' do
          post :create, { tournament_id: @tournament, player: FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:invalid_player) }
          response.should render_template :new
        end
      end
    end

  end
```

Controller:

```
class PlayersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_tournament
  before_action :set_admin, only: [:edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :authenticate_user!, only: [:new, :create, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  def index
    @players = @tournament.players.all
  end

  def show
    @player = Player.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
    @player = @tournament.players.new
  end

  def create
    if current_user.player.nil? == false
      flash[:error] = "You're already in tournament."
      redirect_to tournaments_url
    else
      @player = @tournament.players.new
      @player.user_id = current_user.id
      if @player.save
        redirect_to @tournament
      else
        render 'new'
      end
    end
  end

  def edit
    if current_user == @admin
      @player = @tournament.players.find(params[:id])
    else
      redirect_to tournaments_url
    end
  end

  def update
    if current_user == @admin
      @player = @tournament.players.find(params[:id])
      if @player.update_attributes(game_params)
        flash[:success] = "Player was updated successful"
        redirect_to @tournament
      end
    else
      redirect_to tournaments_url
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @player = Player.find(params[:id])
    flash[:success] = "Player deleted"
    redirect_to @tournament
  end

  private

  def set_tournament
    @tournament = Tournament.find(params[:tournament_id])
  end

  def set_admin
    @tournament = Tournament.find(params[:tournament_id])
    @admin = @tournament.user
  end
end
```

Comment: Do some debugging with `binding.pry` or `byebug`. Figure out what attributes are actually being passed into your controller and why your model layer isn't rejecting them.

Comment: Try to print the last saved `Player.last` using `puts` and see whether it is saved.

Comment: Validation [is only triggered](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#when-does-validation-happen-questionmark) by `create`, `create!`, `save`, `save!`, `update` and `update!`. So if your controller stores the player [in any other way](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#skipping-validations), it'll go into the database without validation.

Comment: Please post your controller code.

Comment: @das-g Then why player with attributes :player, can't be saved, if one of that attributes is invalid?

Comment: Eek, don't test for `== false`. Use `unless`, or even better, use `if` and handle the positive case first.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not assigning any attributes to your model in your create method. You need to do the following (I assume it's rails 4):

```
@player = @tournament.players.new(player_params)

#...

private 

def player_params
  params.require(:player).permit(:wins, :loses, :draws)
end
```

Without any assignment you most likely falling back onto database default value of zero, which is valid.

Comment: Well, i'm little bit ashamed.I thought, that it's unnecessary to put that part of code there, because attributes for player, are set in my database. Also why half of my test worked, without code from your answer?

Comment: @Nekron - This code is necessary for a security reason - just because you have a column in database does not mean it is writeable from the external world (common scenario - admin column in user model can only be set by other admins usually). Since your action does not raise any exception (but always create a record in the database) there is no reason for other tests to fail.